# 2 kubernetes cronjobs that mount to the same directory, mount file Deleting the Existing Files

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, cron

I created 2 Kubernetes cronjobs.
1 cronjob for backups the Mariradb and the second cronjob backups the PostgreSQL.
[mariradb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpVPy.png)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: deploy-cron-job-mariadb
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
         labels:
          cj2job: cronjob
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: cron-user
          volumes:
            - name: deploy-script
              configMap:
                name: deploy-script
          containers:
          - name: cron-job-mariadb-1
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            env:
            - name: mariadb-user
              value: "bla"
            - name: mariadb-password
              value: "bla"
            command: ["bash", "/var/backups/deployScript.sh"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: deploy-script
              mountPath: /var/backups
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60
```

[postgres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuHct.png)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: deploy-cron-job-postgresql
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
         labels:
          cj2job: cronjob
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: cron-user
          volumes:
            - name: deploy-script
              configMap:
                name: deploy-script
          containers:
          - name: cron-job-postgresql-1
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            env:
            - name: postgresql-user
              value: "bla"
            - name: postgresql-password
              value: "bla"
            command: ["bash", "/var/backups/deployScript.sh"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: deploy-script
              mountPath: /var/backups
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60
```

I have an ansible playbook that deploys these 2 cronjob files :
[ansible playbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj1Eo.png)

And just the second deployment is mount to the /var/backups directory, in this case, the PostgreSQL but if the Mariradb was the second one so his backups were in the directory

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cDeR.png)

If I run the kubectl apply command manually on the file it will work, but I want to do it with my ansible playbook automatically.

Comment: What is the error that you are facing? And you might want to add the yaml files with proper indentation as well please? It's easier for the readers.

Comment: @codeaprendiz 
I didn't get an error. It seems like it is working but I think the PostgreSQL cronjob runs over the MariaDB one. 
Is the indentation not proper?

Comment: If you need access to the backups. Before you run the second cronjob you can use `kubectl cp` command to copy the backup on the target server to a specific location. Then do the same after the second command as well. The identation is good. Maybe add the ansible-playbook as well.

Comment: I guess you issue is because the path of your backup script is overwriting the current files. Is it correct? in this case, why not change the path? by default, if you try to mount some volume on top of an existent foler, it will overwrite you current files, it's a expected behaviour.

Comment: Hi @Mr.KoopaKiller
so I actually changed that and the MariaDB volume mount to /var/backups/mariadb
and the Postgresql to /var/backups/postgresql 
and it still doesn't work

Comment: @AdiBenDavid try to use [subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) to mount your file, it shouldn't overwrite the directory content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

backups.sh file (backups script):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
    kubectl exec -it postgres-0 -n blabla -- bash -c "PGPASSWORD="postgres" pg_dump -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 dealer > /var/backups/postgresql.sql1"
    kubectl exec -it postgres-0 -n blabla -- bash -c "mv /var/backups/postgresql.sql1 /var/backups/postgresql-$date.sql1"
    kubectl cp postgres-0:/var/backups/postgresql-$date.sql1 /var/backups/postgresql-$date.sql1 -n blabla
    
    kubectl exec -it mariadb-0 -n blabla -- bash -c "mysqldump monitor -u root -p123456 > /var/backups/mysql.dump"
    kubectl exec -it mariadb-0 -n blabla -- bash -c "mv /var/backups/mysql.dump /var/backups/mysql-$date.dump"
    kubectl cp mariadb-0:/var/backups/mysql-$date.dump /var/backups/mysql-$date.dump -n blabla
```

cronjobs.sh file (4 last files in the folder):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/backups
ls -lt | tail -n +6 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm -rf
```

skipper.sh (scheduler):

```
#!/bin/bash
mv docker-playbook/files/cronjobs.sh /var/
mv docker-playbook/files/backups.sh /var/
cat <<EOF | crontab -
0  0  *  *  * bash /var/backups.sh
0  1  *  *  * bash /var/cronjobs.sh
EOF
```